# Add element to row csr matrix (concatenate a column to matrix) in scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have looked online for the past 4 hours and I have not been able to find a solution to this that works. It's such a stupid problem that I didn't want to ask it so I wouldn't get downvoted, but here goes nothing.

### The task:

I have a (1x`N`) csr matrix and I want to simply make it (1x`N+1`) matrix by adding the number "1" to the end.

### Everything I tried and the errors:

**`vstack(xi, np.ones((1,1)))`**:

*`TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')`*

**`hstack(xi, np.ones((1,1)))`**:

*`ValueError: blocks must be 2-D`*

**`np.concatenate([xi, [np.ones(1)]])`**:

*`ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated`*

**`xi = np.concatenate([xi, np.ones(1)])`**:

*`ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated`*

and *so* many variants of the above... please anybody help I've been on this for so long and I'm thinking of giving up on this entire project.

Comment: A `csr` matrix is not a numpy array.  Many numpy functions don't work with it.  Use the `sparse` functions.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html

Comment: Yes, that worked. This is what did it: `hstack([xi, np.ones(1)])` apparently I was two square brackets away from the right answer. Please post an answer so I can accept it as a solution!

Comment: Yes, the sparse `hstack` wants a list, just like the `np.hstack`.  It'll be worth your while to look at its code (and at `bmat`).